# Scanning a integer from a character array

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int a[10];
    for (int i=0 ; i<10;i++){
        a[i]=0;
    }

    char *str = (char *)malloc(1024*sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s",str);
    str = realloc(str, strlen(str)+1);

    for (int i = 0;i<strlen(str);i++){

        for ( int j = 0;j<=9;j++){
            if(*str=='j') a[j]++;
        }

        str++;
    }
    for (int i=0 ; i<10;i++){
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In this code  during the `if(*str=='j') a[j]++;` the condition `*str == j` is always returning false, due to which the value of `a[j]` is not changing at all.

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix this?

The code is supposed to scan for integer in a given array and give the frequency of the digit occured.

Example Input : `a11472o5t6`

Output : `0 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0`

Comment: Please fix your code. It has some unintended insertions there. Also correct the indentation.

Comment: What's the purpose of `str = realloc(str, strlen(str)+1);` here? It's pretty pointless.

Comment: And what is the program supposed to do? Please show an example of input and expected output.

Comment: Why would the condition be true anyways? What is your input? It will be only true if the input is starting with `'j'`

Comment: @EugeneSh. The input may be any character or any number.
If at any j (say j=5) *str is equal to j ( or 5 in this case ) I intend to update a[j] (or a[5]) .

Comment: So.. ? What is that `'j'` magic then? Why are you comparing to it?

Comment: I'm trying to check if `*str=='j'` meaning if like in the test case the second character == 1 or not. 

By the way is there any other way to do this? @EugeneSh.

Comment: I don't understand, sorry. You are comparing the first character to `'j'` that's it. There is no second character or `1` anywhere.

Comment: You should consider using `<ctype.h>` and `isdigit()` — and if it is a digit, then you can subtract `'0'` from the digit's value to get the correct index into `a`.  You should not be looping to find out which digit it is.  Also, consider adding appropriate print statements to see what's going on, and don't forget to end lines of output with a newline character.  (See [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) too.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think perhaps what you want is `if(*str=='0'+j) a[j]++;`

In other words, if j is zero, check for a '0' character; if j is 1, check for '1', and so on

Answer (score 0):

- The `str = realloc(str, strlen(str)+1);` step is pointless. You could just delete this line.
- Comparison to `j` is pointless. Since you are counting digits, it should be `'0' + j` instead.
- Instead of advancing `str` with `str++` I suggest `str[i]`. This way you still have your original `str` pointer around in case you want to pass it into `printf` or `strlen` for example.

For the inner loop try this instead:

```
for ( int j = 0; j <= 9; j++ )
{
    if(str[i] == ('0' + j)) a[j]++;
}
```

Comment: `str` is advanced by `str++`.... but this will confuse the `strlen()` test, so yes. There's a problem

Comment: Uhm why would you do that instead of what I do in the answer?

Comment: I was just commenting on your remark "You never advance str" which isn't accurate.

Comment: "You never advance str" is an accurate statement. `str` is never advanced in OP's code. But instead of advancing it, I proposed accessing the char to compare with `str[i]`.

Comment: Oops totally missed that, you are correct. I still prefer `str[i]` though.